# Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, parsing, plugins

I am trying to install an old plugin(i know not the smartest Idea).  But when trying to activate the plugin I am getting the error below

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/kofthitscounter/wp-KOFThitscounter.php on line 167

The plugin is compatible up to WP version 3.5.2 and we are on 3.8 so I think it something on line 167 may need to be re-scripted.

here is the code blow for that file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-38371699-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: KOFT Hits Counter
Author URI: http://www.Knowledgeonfingertips.com
Description: KOFT Post Hits Counter displays the number of hits / views on each of page or post. A simple count indicates how many times a page has been accessed or opened.
Version: 1.5
Author: Knowledgeonfingertips.com
Author URI: http://www.Knowledgeonfingertips.com
*/
global $wpdb;
define('HC_TABLE_NAME', $wpdb->prefix . 'KOFT_hitcount');
define('HC_PATH', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/KOFThitcounter');
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
$themename = "KOFTMenu";
$shortname = "KM";
$position = '63.3'; 
$icon = $file_dir."/images/koft.png";
// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages');
// action function for above hook
function mt_add_pages() {
     # add submenu
  $mincap=get_option('KOFT_mincap');
  if($mincap == '') {
    $mincap="level_2";
  }
  add_menu_page('KOFT Admin', 'KOFT Admin', $mincap, __FILE__, 'iniKOFT', plugins_url('KOFThitscounter/images/KOFT.png',dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))));
  add_submenu_page(__FILE__, __('Check Hits','KOFT'), __('Check Hits','KOFT'), $mincap, __FILE__ . '&KOFT_action=overview', 'iniKOFT');
    add_submenu_page(__FILE__, __('Visit Website','KOFT'), __('Visit Website','KOFT'), $mincap,  __FILE__ . '&KOFT_action=redirect', 'iniKOFT');
}
function iniKOFT() 
{
    if(isset($_GET['KOFT_action']))
    {
      if ($_GET['KOFT_action'] == 'redirect')
      { 
           iniKOFTRedirect();      
      } 
      elseif ($_GET['KOFT_action'] == 'overview')
      {
           iniKOFTMain();
      }
    }else iniKOFTMain();
}
function iniKOFTRedirect() {
  echo "<script language=javascript>window.location.href= 'http://www.knowledgeonfingertips.com'</script>";
}
/**
 * Show overwiew
 */
function iniKOFTMain() 
{
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "KOFT_hitcount";
  $querylimit="LIMIT 50";
  # Tabella Last hits
   "<div class='wrap'><h2>". __('Top Page Hits','KOFT'). "</h2><table class='widefat'><thead><tr><th colspan='2' scope='col'><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3100332509000145";
/* KOFT ads on WP */
google_ad_slot = "3185802680";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></th></tr><tr><th scope='col'>". __('Page Url','KOFT'). "</th><th scope='col'>". __('Hit Count','KOFT'). "</th></tr></thead>";
  print "<tbody id='the-list'>";    

  $KOFTdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER bY hit DESC $querylimit");
  foreach ($KOFTdrafts as $KOFTdrafts) 
  {
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>". $KOFTdrafts->name ."</td>";
    print "<td>". $KOFTdrafts->hit ."</td>";
    print "</tr>";
  }
  print "</table></div>";
}
function KOFThitcounter_install(){
global $wpdb;
if ( $wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE "' . HC_TABLE_NAME . '"') != HC_TABLE_NAME )
{
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `". HC_TABLE_NAME . "` (";
$sql .= "`SN` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,";
$sql .= "`name` VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL,";
$sql .= "`hit` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',";
$sql .= "PRIMARY KEY ( `SN` )";
$sql .= ") ENGINE = MYISAM;";
$wpdb->query($sql);
 }
} 
function KOFThitcounter_uninstall(){
global $wpdb;
$sql = "DROP TABLE `". HC_TABLE_NAME . "`;";
$wpdb->query($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'KOFThitcounter_install');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'KOFThitcounter_uninstall');?>
<?php
function KOFThitcounter_curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
function get_KOFThitcounter(){
$url = KOFThitcounter_curPageURL();
    $url = str_replace ("http://",'',$url);
    $url = str_replace ("www.",'',$url);
    if ($url != "")
        {
            $query = "Select hit from `". HC_TABLE_NAME . "` where name = '$url'"; 
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result) 
            {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            if (mysql_affected_rows()==0)
            {
                $query = "Insert into `". HC_TABLE_NAME . "` (name) values ('$url')";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                echo " Total Views: 1 ";
                if (!$result) 
                {
                    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $hitcount = mysql_result($result, 0);
                $hitcount++;
                echo " Total Views: $hitcount ";
                $query = "Update `". HC_TABLE_NAME . "` set hit = $hitcount where name = '$url'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                if (!$result) 
                {
                    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }?>
<?php }
//admin setting
add_action('admin_menu', 'KOFThitcounter_menu');
function KOFThitcounter_menu() {
add_options_page('Plugin KOFThitcounter', 'KOFThitcounter Options', 1, 'plugin_KOFThitcounter_menu', 'KOFThitcounter_options');
}
function KOFThitcounter_options() {
if (!current_user_can(1))  {
wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
}
echo '
<div class="wrap">';
echo '<h3>Enable KOFT Hits Counter</h3>';
echo 'Just insert the following shortcode anywhere in your blog (for use in a widget: use the text-widget and insert the shortcode there) <br/>';
echo '<pre>&lt;?php get_KOFThitcounter();?&gt;</pre>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that PHP has finished analyzing your code, but you forgot to close a symbol somewhere in your page or in those that were included.

**Situations:**

- You forgot to close a quote, so PHP is continuing to analyze your code until it finds the closing quotation mark.
- You forgot to close a bracket, so from the last opening, PHP considers all the code that
  follows as part of a block that never ends.
- You forgot to close a parenthesis, so from the last open parenthesis, PHP considers all the code that follows as part of a specific block (condition, arguments of functions etc) that does not end.
- You forgot a comma, so for PHP there is an instruction in your code that has no end.

This means that the problem may not be on the line mentioned in the error message, as the missing symbol could be anywhere after (or before) that point.

So your problem is in `function iniKOFTMain()`.
Replace this...

```
"<div class='wrap'><h2>". __('Top Page Hits','KOFT'). "</h2><table class='widefat'><thead><tr><th colspan='2' scope='col'>
```

with this...

```
echo "<div class='wrap'><h2>". __('Top Page Hits','KOFT'). "</h2><table class='widefat'><thead><tr><th colspan='2' scope='col'>"?>
```

And this...

```
</th></tr><tr><th scope='col'>". __('Page Url','KOFT'). "</th><th scope='col'>". __('Hit Count','KOFT'). "</th></tr></thead>";
```

with this...

```
<?php echo"</th></tr><tr><th scope='col'>". __('Page Url','KOFT'). "</th><th scope='col'>". __('Hit Count','KOFT'). "</th></tr></thead>";
```